# Problem while finding duplicate value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have one array and i want to check, array contain duplicate element or not.

I try below code. This code give "CustomNumber" of undefined error, at last stage.

Please Help.

```
 for(var i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++) 
 {
    for(var j = i; j <= myArray.length; j++) 
    {
        if(i != j && myArray[i].CustomNumber == myArray[j].CustomNumber) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Error** : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CustomNumber' of undefined

Comment: `for(var j = i; j <= myArray.length; j++) `  error is your use of `<=` You are accessing `myArray[myArray.length]`

Comment: @dustytrash doubt it

Comment: The most obvious error is `<= length` because first indice is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both j and i will exceed the boundaries of the array.

Array indices range from 0 to length - 1.
So, in your loop `for(var j = i; j <= myArray.length; j++)` The last iteration will fail as you will be trying to reference beyond the end of the array.
Similarly with the `for(var i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++)`.

You should be checking for i ( or j ) less than the length of the array :

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) 
{
   for(var j = i; j < myArray.length; j++) 
   {
       if(i != j && myArray[i].CustomNumber == myArray[j].CustomNumber) 
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
}
```